# Handling multiple view controllers in swift 4

Tags: swift4

newbie here... my root view controller has the following code:

```
func showVC1() {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first")
    self.present(vc1, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

func showVC2() {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    self.present(vc2, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

I can call these functions in either order, the first works fine, but the second will give me an error like "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

I think I want to keep all of my code in the root vc that contains these functions.  How can I make this work?

I'm also concerned that each time I call these functions I'll be creating new vc instances which will use more memory.  Is there a way to keep a reference to these vc's outside of these functions?  And will that solve the hierarchy issue?

Comment: Could you Provide more information about your app navigation flow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, second gives an error because you are trying to present two view controller at the same time from root view controller.

You can create lazy references to these view controllers

```
lazy var firstViewController : FirstViewController = {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
        return vc1
    }()

 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.present(firstViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thx!  I had to also self.dismiss the current vc before I presented one... but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of presenting a new view controller try to push that one into the navigation stack  like

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

Because if you present anything on your controller it will not continue the navigation. which will lead to crash